# iOS IAP ErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" from LIVE APP's MANY USERS

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I've seen some threads on this but all are related to sandbox/ test account.
Here we see **this error a lot from our real users.** 
 Many transactions go through without a problem, but still we receive the error back a lot for some reason.

Also oddly, we see more errors from UAE, and to lesser extent from other Middle Eastern countries, than we expect based on revenues or user volume.

Our app is not really usable when offline, so in many cases Internet connection itself should not be the cause.

1. Does anyone know why/in what conditions we get the error in REAL
   LIVE ENVIRONMENT FROM USERS?
2. What kind of error messages users would see?
3. Is there any way to reduce it?
4. Does the error come back even if the transaction is eventually successful (i.e., duplicate count)?
5. Does that matter if user's location at the time of purchase and iTunes (Apple) account's country does not match? That's sometimes the case for our app because many users are travelers/ expats etc.

Cheers,

Comment: We are seeing exactly the same problem – found no help unfortunatelly... Just voting up hoping someone will be able to shed some light on it