# Consumable product purchases give "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit

There are lots of questions related to this error but I think mine is a little different. I've got one non-consumable product and four consumable products in my game. Non-consumable product is used to unlock game levels and consumable products are used for in-game currency. A typical scenario.

Non-consumable product purchases work without problems but a majority of the users get "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" when they try to buy one of my consumable products.

**EDIT: This is turning into a serious problem. Users are getting Cannot connect to iTunes Store error but it seems the purchases are successful. They are charged by iTunes Store. Any help is greatly appreciated.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Store Kit "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359739/iphone-store-kit-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408968/ios-iap-errordomain-code-0-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-from-live-apps-many